# How to display multiple strings into one Toast?

Tags: android

I made some strings that I could display using a Toast but I'm having trouble figuring out how to make them appear at the same time as a single Toast. So far I have this:

```
String text = input.getText().toString();
String text2= input2.getText().toString();
String text3 = input3.getText().toString();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Name: " + text,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Age: " + text2,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Occupation: " + text3,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

When I run the emulator, it shows the Toasts one at a time. Is there a way to display the name, age, and occupation at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concatenate all of them together.

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
       "Name: " + text 
     + " Age: " + text2 
     + " Occupation: " + text3,
     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Toast.makeText(this, "data = " +t_amount+ "" +order_no+ "" +ph_no, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
String data = "Name: " + text + "\n" + " Age: " + text2 + "\n" + " Occupation: " + text3;
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Or String data = String.Format("Name: {0}\nAge: {1}\nOccupation: {2}", text, text2, text3); or using interpolated strings in C#6 String data = $"Name: {text}\nAge: {text2}\nOccupation: {text3}";